# Build binary and dependencies without sudo

Tags: compiling, source, dependencies

I want to install a piece of software (rtorrent) from source to my home folder. It depends on ncurses, which is not installed. I've installed ncurses to my home folder by using the `PREFIX` option during the configuration step, but this doesn't seem to work when I try to do the same with rtorrent, as it keeps telling me that it requires ncurses.

The last few lines of output during `make`:

```
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... no
checking for NcursesW wide-character library... no
checking for Ncurses library... no
checking for Curses library... no
configure: error: requires either NcursesW or Ncurses library
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most `configure` scripts allow you to specify the location of libraries they use.

```
./configure ... --with-ncurses=some/path ...
```

Comment: Looks like it's `--with-sysroot` in the case of rtorrent.